# Are sound waves affected by electromagnetic fields and if so, how?

Tags: waves

I am interested on the effects of sound waves as they encounter objects and other waves. Lots of info available on object interaction. Less on other waves.

Comment: ordinary air. so I believe it acts as charged.

Answer (score 2):

Sound waves are pressure waves, meaning that they simply are a compression of the medium (which can essentially be any fluid) that propagates by means of the pressure they exert on that same medium. Electromagnetic fields only affect charged particles, so at this point your question can have two different answers, depending on whether the medium is ionized (plasma) or not.

If the sound wave is being propagated in a neutral fluid (for instance air), the presence of an electromagnetic field will have no effect at all. If, however, the medium is ionized (again, a plasma like what can be found in the Earth's magnetosphere), the motion of the plasma generated by the sound wave will be affected by the local electromagnetic fields.

However, when studying these waves they are not regarded as simple sound waves anymore, but as 'magnetosonic' waves, and they have different properties (for instance, the propagation speed depends on the strength of the magnetic field).

So in short no, sound waves are not affected by electromagnetic fields.